# Map where the key is a type, and the value are generics based on this type

Tags: generics, rust

I'm still learning rust, and wanted to know if there was a way to have a map where keys are types, and values are generics using that type.
Something like this:

```
// some generic struct
struct MyStruct<T> {
    someData: T,
}

// what i would like to do
let myMap: Map<T, MyStruct<T>> = Map::new();
```

I've looked up to things as [anymap](https://crates.io/crates/anymap), but it doesn't seems to do what I want.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can do something similar to `anymap` even if not exactly the same.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete use case? Where does that generic parameter come from?

Comment: For instance, `struct Parent<T> { map: HashMap<T, MyStruct<T>> }` is completely valid. What is the context of your code example?

Comment: @PitaJ For context, I'm trying to make an entity component system, and this map would be the components table. The generic parameter represents component structs, and I would like to have a map that stores <T, Vec<T>> to easely iterate over component type. (I've made a wrapper around Vec<T>, it's actually a ComponentArray<T>). 
I didn't knew if i should've stayed as generic as possible or if i should give concrete examples.

Comment: @PitaJ I don't want the hasmap itself to be a generic. It should take the T type as entry, so it would be like HashMap<TypeId, MyStruct<That type of this id>>

Comment: Why exactly can't you use `anymap` and pass in `MyStruct<T>` as the type?

Comment: If you wish to enforce that, you could create a trait `MyStructOnly` that only `MyStruct` implements, and use `anymap::Map<Any + MyStructOnly>`

Comment: @PitaJ I havn't looked too deep into the anymap, but it feels like there is no guaranty that the value at the key T is indeed MyStruct<T>, so later one this could come with issues ?

Comment: Consider using an ECS that already exists. There are a dozen or so crates implementing ECS on Rust. In particular, take a look at [legion](https://crates.io/crates/legion).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `anymap` for this, and just always pass `MyStruct<T>` as the type. You can enforce that only `MyStruct` can be used by creating a `MyStructOnly` trait that only `MyStruct` impls.

```rust
// some generic struct
struct MyStruct<T> {
    someData: T,
}

trait MyStructOnly {}
impl MyStructOnly for MyStruct {}

type Map = anymap::Map<anymap::any::Any + MyStructOnly>;

// what i would like to do
let myMap = Map::new();

myMap.insert(MyStruct { someData: String::from("Hello, World!") });
let hello_world = myMap.get::<MyStruct<String>>();
```